# rsync sub-trees that have a certain name?

Tags: rsync

Hoping this is the right place to ask this...

I have a directory tree like this:

```
r/a/src/etc...
r/a/target/etc...
r/a/xyz/etc...
r/b/src/etc...
r/b/target/etc...
r/c/src/etc...
r/c/target/etc...
```

Ideally, what I need to do is to get the `target` directories, and their contents, to a remote server, preserving the overall tree structure.  Like:

```
r/a/target/etc...
r/b/target/etc...
r/c/target/etc...
```

If it's possible to do this with `rsync` exclude/include/filters, I'm baffled.  I'm hoping it's possible, though, since otherwise it's a bit of a pain.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be simple using the following command:

```
$ rsync -aR r/*/target /destination
```

The `/destination` path can be local or on different machine. The `-R` option is important to preserve the tree structure. Only the target folders (with their contents) will be copied to `/destination` while preserving the tree structure.

Comment: Khaled - that's it; works like a charm.  Not sure why I had so much trouble parsing the `man` page to figure it out.

Comment: It's ok. We are here to help each other.